# INARFIMA (integer-valued autoregressive fractionally integerated moving average), where is the error?

Tags: time-series, random-variable

In http://www.usbe.umu.se/digitalAssets/9/9491_ues673.pdf the author specifies a model which I am working on implementing.

There is a function defined
$d_i = \frac{\Gamma (i + d)}{\Gamma (i + 1) \Gamma (d)}$
where $0 \le d \le 1$ and then the function of d defined
$D = 1 + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} d_i$
yet $D$ diverges $\infty$ so how can this possibly be correct? There must be some mistake and I would appreciate it if someone could try to understand what the author was conveying or if I have completely missed something obvious.

Update: the paper is clearly in error.

Comment: Why don't you email him at shahid.quoreshi@econ.umu.se

Comment: I tried. it bounced. i might have found him on linkedin but he has only 1 connection so the account might not be active

Comment: You can get him at Blekinge Institute of Technology ... Karlskrona, Blekinge, SWEDEN

Comment: Thank you.. I've emailed him there, http://www2.bth.se/mam/forskning.nsf/pages/e0bddfea07bba2cec125791a00369a2e?OpenDocument

Comment: The author hasn't responded. I'm beginning to suspect that he doesn't want to acknowledge he made a mistake in the paper. Or fell off the face of the earth or is just busy but even then it's not hard that to reply to an email.